# Join two tables with Sum of column in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables as shown below..
i need to join two tables using join in sql query but i am new for this so please help me..
as i need output table as shown in third table

### tbl_MonthList

```
MonthID  MonthList
1         January
2         February
3         March
4         April
5         May
6         June
7         July
8         August
9         September
10        October
11        November
12        December
```

### tbl_Amount:

```
Month_id    Amount_Received    Customer_id
3              500             aaa
3             1000             bbb
4              700             jjj
5              300             aaa
5              400             jjj
5              500             ppp
7             1000             aaa
10            1500             bbb
12             700             jjj
```

### I need output as shown below

```
Month         Total_amount
January            0
February           0
March           2000
April            700
May             1200
June               0
July            1000
August             0
September          0
October         1500
November           0
December         700
```

Comment: I just tidied up your data, why did you undo that?  I suggest that you re-edit your question, highlight the tables of example data and click the `{}` button.  This will make the text fixed width and make the data significantly easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  tbl_MonthList.MonthList                        AS Month,
  COALESCE(SUM(tbl_Amount.Amount_Received), 0)   AS Total_amount
FROM
  tbl_MonthList
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_Amount
    ON tbl_MonthList.MonthID = tbl_Amount.month_id
GROUP BY
  tbl_MonthList.MonthList
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that you still get every row from `tbl_MonthList`, even if there are no matching rows in `tbl_Amount`.

Then it's a normal `SUM()` with a `GROUP BY`.

As the `SUM()` of no data *(Like month 1 in your example)* is `NULL`, we use `COALESCE()` to turn that `NULL` into `0`.

Please also note that your `MonthID` and `month_id` field names are not consistent.

Comment: If i have to add one more column name from different table as same as tbl_MonthList table ?

Comment: Pardon?  I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.month,SUM(t2.amount) as SUM FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN  Table2 t2 ON t1.monthid = t2.monthid GROUP BY t1.monthid
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931b0/10)

Comment: You can't select `t1.month` and yet `GROUP BY t2.month_id`.  Even in MySQL doing this means that you're not returning all 12 required results.  `GROUP BY t1.month_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(PINJAM.Tgl) AS Peminjam, DatePart("yyyy",[Tgl]) AS Tahun, DatePart("m",[Tgl]) AS Bulan, IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=1,"Januari",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=2,"Februari",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=3,"Maret",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=4,"April",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=5,"Mei",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=6,"Juni",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=7,"Juli",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=8,"Agustus",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=9,"September",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=10,"Oktober",IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])=11,"November","Desember"))))))))))) AS Ket
FROM PINJAM
GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[Tgl]), DatePart("m",[Tgl]), Format([Tgl],"m/yyyy"), IIf(DatePart("m",[Tgl])>1,"Januari","Februari")
ORDER BY DatePart("yyyy",[Tgl]), DatePart("m",[Tgl]);
```